# Proving one term is greater than the other using limits?

Tags: limits

I would like to show that $$(1-P(x_1)) \le \frac{(1-P(x_2))(M+(1-p)B)}{(M+B)}$$

For all $$x_1 \lt x_2$$ ,  $$P(x_1) \ge P(x_2)$$

and $$P(x_j) \le 1$$, $$p \le 1$$

How could I show this? Could I use limits? Or any other method?

Comment: The question refers to $B(x_j)$ so it seems a function, but in the desired inequality the $B$ appears without any $x_j$ as if it is  constant.

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably $M,B>0$, so your inequality is equivalent to
$$
(1-P(x_1))(M+B) \leq (1-P(x_2))(M+(1-p)B),
$$
which is, however, false. Take $P(x_1) = P(x_2) = 0$, $M=B=1$, $p=1/2$, and the inequality reads $2 \leq 3/2$.